# Jquery validation for currency field

Tags: jquery, css

I have a textfield and i need to bring the currency validations for that.

For ex: if the user enters 1999 then it should display 1999.00 in that textbox.

and if he enters 19.50 then it should diplay 19.50 only.

Is this achievable using CSS? if Yes could you please tell me how to do that?

or else provide me Jquery validation for this.

Comment: CSS can't do that. CSS is only about styling the look of your HTML.

Comment: You could use var.toFixed(2) in plain javascript

Comment: Please Provide me Jquery validation for this

Answer (score 0):

```
FormatAsMoney(document.getElementById("yourElementId"), 10000000000, true);

function FormatAsMoney(txtbox, upperlimit, useDecimal) 
{
    nStr = stripComma(txtbox.value);
    txtbox.value = FormatAsMoneyFromString(nStr, upperlimit, useDecimal);
}

function FormatAsMoneyFromString(nStr, upperlimit, useDecimal) {
    if(!isNaN(nStr)&& nStr != "")
    {
        if (upperlimit != null && (nStr * 1) <= upperlimit)
        {
            var amount = nStr * 1;
            nStr = amount.toString();
            nStr += '';
            x = nStr.split('.');
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = (typeof(x[1]) == 'undefined')?'00':x[1];
            x2 = (x2.length == 1)?x2+'0':x2;
            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (rgx.test(x1)) 
            {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }
            if (useDecimal)
            {
                return  x1 + '.' + x2;
            }
            else
            {
                return x1;
            }
        }
    }

return nStr;
}

function stripComma(money)
{
    var retVal = ""
    if( money != null )
    {
        retVal = money;
        if(retVal.indexOf(',') != -1) // strip the commas
        {
            var strip = retVal.split(',');
            retVal = "";

            for(var y=0;y< parseInt(strip.length);y++)
            {
                retVal += strip[y];
            }

        }
        if(retVal.indexOf(' ') != -1) // strip the spaces
        {
            var strip = retVal.split(' ');
            retVal = "";

            for(var y=0;y< parseInt(strip.length);y++)
            {
                retVal += strip[y];
            }

        }

    }
    return retVal;
} // end stripComma
```